# Swift3 center Item in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to center UIImageView in UICollectionViewCell custom class with below code but not works

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
}
```

I am setting cell width and height too

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)])
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)])
```

what I am doing wrong?

**EDITED**
 full code what I am trying to archive

```
import UIKit

class MenuBar: UIView,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {

        let verticalLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: verticalLayout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 32, blue: 31)
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()

    let cellId:String = "cellId"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        addSubview(collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)


    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MenuCell:BaseCell{

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        //backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        addSubview(imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)])
    }

    let imageView:UIImageView = {
        let iv:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "home")

        return iv
    }()

}

extension UIView{
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format:String, views:UIView...){
        var viewsDictionary = [String:UIView]()

        for(index, view) in views.enumerated(){
            let key:String = "v\(index)"

            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view


        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

    }
}

extension UIColor{
    static func rgb(red:CGFloat,green:CGFloat,blue:CGFloat)->UIColor{
        return UIColor(colorLiteralRed: Float(red/255), green: Float(green/255), blue: Float(blue/255), alpha: 1)
    }
}



class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the constraints code?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you mean *"not works"*? Your imageView isn't there? It's the wrong size? In the wrong place? The cells are the wrong size? Are you getting an error? Warnings? Where is this code that you've shown... in a Cell class? In a UIView class? In your controller class?

Comment: Why not override `init(frame: CGRect)` and set it up there? I do that often.

Comment: @DonMag regarding your comment I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Visual Format Language *can* be convenient, it can also remove some of the "explicitness" of constraints, and makes it easy to miss some obvious things...

In your `MenuCell` class, you add `imageView` as a subview, and then you call:

```
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
```

The pipe / vertical bar symbol "|" tells auto-layout that the view is "pinned" to the edge of its superview. In your case, you are both explicitly setting the size of `imageView` **and** the size of the cell (in `sizeForItemAt`) **and** you are saying "pin the sides of imageView to the sides of the cell." Something won't be satisfied.

If you simply remove the "|" symbols from those two lines:

```
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)
```

you should have a centered 28x28 image view in your cell.

Note: since you follow that with `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` calls, you could also have set those constraints in that manner:

```
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0)])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0)])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)])
```

Using consistent methods may have made that a little less likely to miss.

Comment: I am new in swift, but I see my mistake. you explained everything shortly and very well it works, thanks a lot @DonMag